# Android Camera2 picture is black and video records only 1sec

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-image, android-camera2

I am using Camera2 API with help of the two examples that you can find here:

- [GitHub - Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/)
- [GitHub - Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

I am using identical source code like in the above links, so I wont copy my Source here (unless you require some parts, I will edit my question and post it).

**EDIT:**

Ran some tests. When I try to play the video through my phone, it only displays the first frame and I can hear Audio (voices) that were actually in the recording. Once the video goes until end, the video somehow restarts automatically and displays the video as it should.

However, when I try to play the video on my PC (copying it from Phone to Desktop), I only get black screen until the last frame. Last frame is shown, but the video does not play at all. I can hear Audio (voices) tho.

I am thinking of maybe there's issue with some Video encoding / decoding?

**ISSUE:**

> In my case the Video recording won't work. I
>   can see both files in the directory that they should be on my Phone,
>   but when I play the video
>   (5 second video) **first 4 seconds are black**, then last second is like
>   one Frame of what I recorded and that's it, yet file size seems big (160MB).

**SCREENS:**

- *Will post video once uploaded*

I do not know what is wrong, can someone please help?

Comment: I managed to correct some of my error for Picture Taking. However, I now imported the Sample for Camera2Video example and the issue is same. So probably something is wrong in the Source Example of Camera2Video. I will try to find out what.

Comment: Hey! Are you using basic and video both in once place? I am having issue to use both in same fragment. I wont single view in which user can take photos OR record video. can you please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is not a real solutions, but still it did the trick for what I wanted to do.

In order to play the video I had to **DISABLE AUDIO ENTIRELY** in my MediaRecorder setup:

```
        //mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getVideoFile(activity).getAbsolutePath());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        //mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

You can notice where I can commented out commands. Once I did that, the video plays normally.

Hope this **bad** workaround still will help someone who also does not require audio in the video recording.

Comment: I have an identical problem. I think it is hardware related; I get the issue on my Galaxy S7 but not on my Nexus tablet. Analysing the video file I find that the framerate and minimum framerate is 0 fps even though I am setting the framerate to 30. Android camera2 api galaxy s7

Answer (score 1):

On some devices notably the Galaxy series, S7 etc. the media-recorder gives bad time-stamp for the video track. this causes the audio to play first followed by video. to fix this, you'll need to reparse the output generated by the media recorder and rewrite the video time stamps, starting from time 0. this will fix the audio video sync issue, you posted above.

Comment: Please give some advice on how to reparse the output.

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung Galaxy S7 (and S6 I think) has a bug which messes up the encoding.
The fix is to reencode using the function below.

Note that you need this dependency in your gradle:
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'

```
    public void fixSamsungBug()
{
    DataSource channel = null;
    try
    {
        channel = new FileDataSourceImpl(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    IsoFile isoFile = null;

    try
    {
        isoFile = new IsoFile(channel);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<TrackBox> trackBoxes = isoFile.getMovieBox().getBoxes(TrackBox.class);
    boolean sampleError = false;
    for (TrackBox trackBox : trackBoxes) {
        TimeToSampleBox.Entry firstEntry = trackBox.getMediaBox().getMediaInformationBox().getSampleTableBox().getTimeToSampleBox().getEntries().get(0);

        // Detect if first sample is a problem and fix it in isoFile
        // This is a hack. The audio deltas are 1024 for my files, and video deltas about 3000
        // 10000 seems sufficient since for 30 fps the normal delta is about 3000
        if(firstEntry.getDelta() > 10000) {
            sampleError = true;
            firstEntry.setDelta(3000);
        }
    }

    if(sampleError) {
        Log.d("gpinterviewandroid", "Sample error! correcting...");
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        for (TrackBox trackBox : trackBoxes) {
            movie.addTrack(new Mp4TrackImpl(channel.toString() + "[" + trackBox.getTrackHeaderBox().getTrackId() + "]" , trackBox));
        }
        movie.setMatrix(isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getMatrix());
        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

        //delete file first!
        File file = new File(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL);
        boolean deleted = file.delete();


        FileChannel fc = null;
        try
        {
            //fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL)).getChannel();
            fc = new RandomAccessFile(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL, "rw").getChannel();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            out.writeContainer(fc);
            fc.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("gpinterviewandroid", "Finished correcting raw video");
    }
}
```

Comment: That didnt fix my video, are you sure this works? Thanks

Comment: The problem is this code is changing my metadata. It was MPEG 4 and now the file seems corrupted. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
```